# Grails createLink doesnt add all arguments to uri

Tags: grails, uri, gsp

So i have a createLink in gsp file like this:

```
${createLink(params:[warehouseId:warehouse?.id, itemId:itemWarehouseInstance?.item?.id], uri: '/item/show/' + itemWarehouseInstance?.item?.id)}
```

and in localhost version it works perfectly and produces following link:

```
.../item/show/2?warehouseId=2&itemId=2
```

BUT when i create .war and deploy it on server it produces following link:

```
.../item/show/4?warehouseId=1
```

which means it didn't add all arguments to the URI.
I am still new to the grails so it might not be big issue, but i have no idea what could have went wrong. If you need any information, just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `itemWarehouseInstance?.item?.id` seems to be null

Comment: that crossed my mind aswell, but the same variable is in link
'/item/show/' + itemWarehouseInstance?.item?.id
and it renders it there perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Well, I rewrote that createLink in this format:

```
createLink(controller: 'item', action: 'show', id: itemWarehouseInstance?.item?.id, params:[warehouseId:warehouse?.id, itemId:itemWarehouseInstance?.item?.id])
```

and it is indeed now working perfectly even on deployed version.

Thanks anyway.